# How to remove outlines around windows when switching with Alt+Tab?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, window-management

When I switch windows on current Unity using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get an ugly outline of size of the selected window occasionally showing on random places. Is there a way to change this outline to something better looking or eliminate it altogether?

**NB** These outlines appear on Ubuntu Desktop without any effects enabled.

**Outlined Firefox**
[image]

**Outlined Nautilus**
[image]

**Outlined Terminal**
[image]

Click on the images to better view the outlines in question.

Comment: @Jorge, you removed the question being related to Unity...

Comment: It's tagged unity and the unity developers are watching the tag so it'll be fine. :)

Comment: @Oxwivi Is it possible to grab a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: @Jorge, it's unrelated to the one in development. And I don't know if I could grab a screen shot while pressing those two keys.

Comment: You can do delayed screenshots. Run `gnome-screenshot -i` and select to grab the whole screen after a delay. This should give you time to create the strange lines. :)

Comment: @Jorge, @htourque, I've included the screeshots in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this in a normal GNOME session (without Compiz running). Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to disable those preview borders (I skimmed through Metacity's source code and couldn't find anything relevant).